# Как сделать свою тему в Yii ?

Tags: yii

Друзья, в папке themes вижу файлы classic, в ней структура папок и все они пустые. В /protected/views - отображение элементов внутри этого каркаса-шаблона.

Как сделать свою тему? В официальной документации мало инфы и нихрена не понятно.
Вот сделаю я свою папку со структурой и файлами. (classic причем пустая, где брать пример?)

Ок, в layouts/main.php - макет страницы главной, а что за представления тогда в site/index.php?

А как прописывать внутри файлов где и что должно выводиться? Что тут этот виджет, там тот вид и т.д.?
Как указать в шаблоне, что именно в этом месте я хочу вывести вид авторизаци, который в /protected/views/autorise.php ?
Где надо хранить css, js, картинки по фэн шую?

Ничего не ясно мне. Где можно почитать подробнее?
Или посмотреть пример? Или видеоурок какой-нибудь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В /protected/views/layouts у вас лежат основные шаблоны для ваших контроллеров, через которые будет выводиться контент, генерируемый вашими экшнами.
т.е, когда вы создали контроллер SomeStuffController, в папке /protected/views/layouts автоматически будет создано представление somestuff.php, которое будет являться базовым для всех экшенов контроллера SomeStuff. Кроме этого, в папке /protected/views будет создан каталог с названием, идентичным названию экшна, в данном случае это будет каталог somestuff, и до него можно будет достучаться по пути /protected/views/somestuff. В этом каталоге будет лежать файл index.php, который будет соответствовать экшену actionIndex контроллера someStuff. Собственно, в этом файле и нужно описывать шаблон, в соответствии с которым будет выводиться контент из экшна index.

Вопрос вообще некорректен.

Comment: Можете помочь еще с этим вопросом?!

Допустим у меня есть страница, которой надо в корне другой каркас (шапка и футер другие).
Я создаю его в layouts/another.php

И как вызвать его для нужной ссылки, к примеру, about?

Comment: почему некорректный вопрос? в YII можно делать свои темы

Comment: Темы основываются на чем? На шаблонах.
Yii - это фреймворк, а не cms, соответственно, как будут выглядеть будущие шаблоны зависит только от разработчика

Comment: butteff, экшн, выводящий контент с другим оформлением находится в том же контроллере, что и остальные, или в другом контроллере?

Answer (score 1):

Темы в YII есть, и оформляются они такойже структурой файлов и папок как и организация представлений в папке protected/views. Главный момент - тему нада подключить в конфиге. И еще если представления в папке с темой не оказалось, YII берет файл представления в protected/views - впринципе все просто и логично.

Подробности вот [тут](http://www.dbhelp.ru/yii-blog-themes/page/)
Лучше там я не распишу да и смысл. Если что непонятно спрашивай.

Answer (score 0):

не нужно создавать свою тему, их и скачать можно.

[например такую](http://www.webapplicationthemes.com/shadow-dancer-yii-framework-theme/)

ну а по факту - нужно одну строку в config/main дописать

```
return array(
'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
'name' => 'myname',
'theme' => 'shadow_dancer',
```

ну а дальще можно разбираться с css темы и прочие хитрости.
[например так](http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/03/yii-yii-for-dummies.html)